# Create scopes using instance methods best way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering what's the best way to make an scope using an instance method to filter records. This is my model:

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :availables, lambda{ all.select{ |obj| obj.is_available? } }

  def is_available?
    Date.today <= Date.strptime(valid_thru, '%m/%d/%Y')
    ...more validations here
  end
end
```

The problem here is this scope returns an array instead of an ActiveRecord::Relation and I'm not able to chain other scopes.

Any suggestion guys?

Comment: Gals can't answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to accomplish what you want. If you want to apply logic on ruby objects you can no longer return an ActiveRecord::Relation.

The only way to achieve something like this is have the logic on a database level. In that case you could use a class method to achieve what you want like so:

```
def availables
  where('valid_thru => ?', Date.today)
end
```